# How to Stop Header, so I can echo to screen from the same function (PHP)

Tags: php, file, header, download

I'm finding Headers a nightmare to get my head around, I have a file the user downloads which works fine. However I then whish to echo to the screen that xx file has been sent; but ofc this echo is just placed inside the sent file.

Full dowload code is as follows:

```
    function download()
{
$orderNo = $_POST['orderNo'];
$lines = file('F:/xamptest/htdocs/UniProject/upload/Amazon output.txt');
$lineCount = count($lines);
if($orderNo>0&&$orderNo<=$lineCount)
{
    $lineEx = explode("\t", $lines[($orderNo-1)]);      
    $file = fopen('Order.txt', 'w');
fwrite($file, $lineEx[8].PHP_EOL .$lineEx[17].PHP_EOL .$lineEx[18].PHP_EOL  .$lineEx[19].PHP_EOL  .$lineEx[20].PHP_EOL  .$lineEx[21].PHP_EOL  .$lineEx[22].PHP_EOL  .$lineEx[23].PHP_EOL);
fclose($file);
$file = 'Order.txt';

ob_end_clean();
header("Cache-Control: private");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file");
header("Content-Type: application/zip");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
readfile($file);
echo "Current order, number: ".$orderNo."<br> Has been downloaded";
}
else
{
echo "Please enter a valid Order Number between 1 and ".$lineCount;
}
}
```

I can't seem to find how to stop the headers without using exit(); which then still means it won't show the echo, and any more use of ob_end_clean(); in any other ways causes the sent file to be empty. Only other thing I could think was having the echo in its own function, but as it runs at the same time the headers do it still places it in the file.

Many thanks for any help - Tom.

Comment: Anything that is output when those headers are sent will be included in the download file. You can't sent another message with the file. So what you have to do is fake it. When you click on a link to this file, you will still be on the linking page. You can use javascript to, on click of the link, display a message. There are several download sites that just link you to a page saying "Your download will start shortly", they display that page and redirect you to a download file (or script that sends headers).

Answer (score 0):

What you're dealing with is an **HTTP request**. The browser *requests* a URL with an HTTP request, the server sends a *response*. Click a link → browser sends request → server sends HTML page in response. Use Chrome, Safari or Firefox + Firebug and play around with the *Network* tab in their Web Inspector/development tools to get a real feeling for what's happening.

If you want to download a file, it works the same way. Only the server tells the browser through HTTP headers that this response is not an ordinary HTML page, but is supposed to be a file which it should save on disk.

As you should be able to see, there's no way to respond with a file download *and* an HTML page at the same time in one response. There's simply no way to do it. You have to output your HTML page with the message first, then link to the file download from there.